# Google DNS Server

Tags: python, sockets, dns, ip

I wanted to get my private IP address using Python, so I found a snippet of code that does it.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```

Here 8.8.8.8 is address for Google DNS server. Now whenever we hit an external site, we are only represented by our public IP address, so how is Google DNS able to find my Private IP address ? Moreover this was working even when my Internet connection was off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to get my private IP address using Python, so I found a snippet of code that does it. ... so how is Google DNS able to find my Private IP address ?

This snippet of code does not do what you expect it to do. All it reports is the local IP address from an UDP socket "connecting" to 8.8.8.8. This information does not come from Google, it comes from your local operating system which of course knows what its local IP address is. In fact, you could connect to any other external IP address and you'll get the same information back.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
```

Apart from that the code is wrong too. It does not connect to the DNS server - the DNS server would be port 53 and not port 80 as you use here.

Comment: Thanks! I get it that DNS works on port 53, but the code is working just fine on any port.

Comment: @NimishAgrawal: It is completely irrelevant to which external destination you connect, and this includes not only IP but also port. Like I said, the local IP address is not retrieved from the peer but from the local system.